# how to add login error flash message in passport js

Tags: javascript, flash

I wish to display a flash message on my log in form, thats when the user gives a wrong credential in the form, but i don't know where to add the flash am confused a bit. anyone around help out please.

```
app.post('/login',passport.authenticate("local", {
successRedirect: "/",
failureRedirect: "/login"
}), function(req, res){
req.flash('error', err.message)
})
```

i would still like it to display the error from the form. am new to this any 
 help

```
req.flash('error', err.message)
```

Answer (score 1):

in login you need to code in failureFlash: true, and set it to true

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
    res.locals.success = req.flash("success")
    next();
})

app.post("/dashlogin", passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/dashboard",
    failureRedirect: "/dashboard/login",
    failureFlash: true,
}),  function(req,res){

})
```

Then flash it to the user it in the page

```
<% if(error && error.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <div class="container">
            <%= error %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your message to `res.locals` like this

```
req.flash('error', 'This is an error message');
res.locals.message = req.flash();
```

Then you can show them in your html like

```
<div class="error-message">
    <strong> <%=message.message%> </strong>
</div>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I know how to set it up, but my confusion is adding it it to the login before it redirects back, so that the flash will display @Nikunj Sardhara

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in server side:

```
    var passport = require('passport');    
    var flash = require('connect-flash');
    app.use(flash());
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
        res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
        res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
        next();
    });
```

where you can add messages in your `passport.js` to be popped up as:

```
req.flash('error_msg', 'That email is already taken.');
req.flash('success_msg', 'This is successfull');
```

and in your front-end code(as per your language. I am using handlebars for front-end templating) display your alert messages:

```
    {{#if success_msg}}
        <div class="alert alert-success">{{success_msg}}</div>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if error_msg}}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error_msg}}</div>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if error}}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
    {{/if}}
```

Comment: setting it up is not a problem but adding it to the login post @HOTAM SINGH